# Pyspark: how to duplicate a row n time in dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

I've got a dataframe like this and I want to duplicate the row n times if the column `n` is bigger than one:

```
A   B   n  
1   2   1  
2   9   1  
3   8   2    
4   1   1    
5   3   3
```

And transform like this:

```
A   B   n  
1   2   1  
2   9   1  
3   8   2
3   8   2       
4   1   1    
5   3   3 
5   3   3 
5   3   3
```

I think I should use `explode`, but I don't understand how it works...
Thanks

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample : it's in python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#explode) function *returns a new row for each element in the given array or map.*

One way to exploit this function is to use a `udf` to create a list of size `n` for each row. Then explode the resulting array.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
    
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,1), (2,9,1), (3,8,2), (4,1,1), (5,3,3)] ,["A", "B", "n"]) 

+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  n|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  9|  1|
|  3|  8|  2|
|  4|  1|  1|
|  5|  3|  3|
+---+---+---+

# use udf function to transform the n value to n times
n_to_array = udf(lambda n : [n] * n, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df2 = df.withColumn('n', n_to_array(df.n))

+---+---+---------+
|  A|  B|        n|
+---+---+---------+
|  1|  2|      [1]|
|  2|  9|      [1]|
|  3|  8|   [2, 2]|
|  4|  1|      [1]|
|  5|  3|[3, 3, 3]|
+---+---+---------+ 

# now use explode  
df2.withColumn('n', explode(df2.n)).show()

+---+---+---+ 
| A | B | n | 
+---+---+---+ 
|  1|  2|  1| 
|  2|  9|  1| 
|  3|  8|  2| 
|  3|  8|  2| 
|  4|  1|  1| 
|  5|  3|  3| 
|  5|  3|  3| 
|  5|  3|  3| 
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I prefere @jxc's answer for spark 2.4+ because it uses all built-ins instead of a udf.

Comment: @DVL Unfortunately some of us are still stuck with previous spark versions...

Comment: @DVL array_repeat does not work on long type column

Answer (score 22):

With **Spark 2.4.0+**, this is easier with builtin functions: **[array_repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_repeat)** + **explode**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,1), (2,9,1), (3,8,2), (4,1,1), (5,3,3)], ["A", "B", "n"])

new_df = df.withColumn('n', expr('explode(array_repeat(n,int(n)))'))

>>> new_df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  n|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  9|  1|
|  3|  8|  2|
|  3|  8|  2|
|  4|  1|  1|
|  5|  3|  3|
|  5|  3|  3|
|  5|  3|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: When using the `array_repeat` API function in pyspark, how can you reference n for the second parameter (count)? I get `Column is not iterable` when trying with `F.col()`.

Comment: @DavidFoster, this can not be done using pyspark API functions, check this *Frequent* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51140470/9510729). using SQL expressions, this is not a problem and IMO the code is often more concise and easy to maintain.

Comment: thanks for confirming that it's not supported. It seems odd that the Python API doesn't support this when it's simple in the underlying SQL. That's a fair point on brevity, however, in this case it looks just like the Python solution would and my IDE will treat it as a string rather than functions/methods etc.

Comment: @jxc array_repeat does not work on long type column

Answer (score 3):

I think the `udf` answer by @Ahmed is the best way to go, but here is an alternative method, that may be as good or better for small `n`:

First, collect the maximum value of `n` over the whole DataFrame:

```
max_n = df.select(f.max('n').alias('max_n')).first()['max_n']
print(max_n)
#3
```

Now create an array for each row of length `max_n`, containing numbers in `range(max_n)`. The output of this intermediate step will result in a DataFrame like:

```
df.withColumn('n_array', f.array([f.lit(i) for i in range(max_n)])).show()
#+---+---+---+---------+
#|  A|  B|  n|  n_array|
#+---+---+---+---------+
#|  1|  2|  1|[0, 1, 2]|
#|  2|  9|  1|[0, 1, 2]|
#|  3|  8|  2|[0, 1, 2]|
#|  4|  1|  1|[0, 1, 2]|
#|  5|  3|  3|[0, 1, 2]|
#+---+---+---+---------+
```

Now we explode the `n_array` column, and filter to keep only the values in the array that are less than `n`. This will ensure that we have `n` copies of each row. Finally we drop the exploded column to get the end result:

```
df.withColumn('n_array', f.array([f.lit(i) for i in range(max_n)]))\
    .select('A', 'B', 'n', f.explode('n_array').alias('col'))\
    .where(f.col('col') < f.col('n'))\
    .drop('col')\
    .show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|  n|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  1|
#|  2|  9|  1|
#|  3|  8|  2|
#|  3|  8|  2|
#|  4|  1|  1|
#|  5|  3|  3|
#|  5|  3|  3|
#|  5|  3|  3|
#+---+---+---+
```

However, we are creating a `max_n` length array for each row- as opposed to just an `n` length array in the `udf` solution. It's not immediately clear to me how this will scale vs. `udf` for large `max_n`, but I suspect the `udf` will win out.