# Duplicate row in PySpark Dataframe based on value in another column and got order

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to create new dataset based on original dataset for example

for example
my input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awFJN.png)

my output should be[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LnzI.png)
I refer other code and got thiss

```
def duplicate_function(row):
    data = []  # list of rows to return
    to_duplicate = float(row["No_of_Occ"])

    i = 0
    while i < to_duplicate:
        row_dict = row.asDict()  # convert a Spark Row object to a Python dictionary
        row_dict["No_of_Occ"] = str(i)
        new_row = Row(**row_dict)  # create a Spark Row object based on a Python dictionary
        to_return.append(new_row)  # adds this Row to the list
        i += 1

    return data  # returns the final list
```

but how can I get the No_of_occ here?

Comment: `no_of_occ == 0` gives you one line ? are you sure of this result ? Please provide text based code, not images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: how to duplicate a row n time in dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624745/pyspark-how-to-duplicate-a-row-n-time-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to duplicate in-line the values as many times as `No_of_Occ` and then use a `posexplode` to generate more lines.

Assuming `df` is your dataframe.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

output_schema = T.ArrayType(df.drop("no_of_occ").schema)

@F.udf(output_schema)
def duplicate(no_of_occ, *args):
    return list((args,) * no_of_occ)

df.select(
    "no_of_occ",
    F.posexplode(duplicate(*df.columns))
).select(
    "no_of_occ",
    (F.col("pos")+1).alias("occ_no"),
    F.col("col.*")
).show()


+---------+------+------+------+
|no_of_occ|occ_no|value1|value2|
+---------+------+------+------+
|        2|     1|     2|     3|
|        2|     2|     2|     3|
|        3|     1|     3|     4|
|        3|     2|     3|     4|
|        3|     3|     3|     4|
|        4|     1|     5|     6|
|        4|     2|     5|     6|
|        4|     3|     5|     6|
|        4|     4|     5|     6|
|        2|     1|     7|     8|
|        2|     2|     7|     8|
|        1|     1|     8|     9|
+---------+------+------+------+
```

need to solve the case where `no_of_occ = 0`.

---

EDIT: 
If you need to keep also the lines with `0` (as `1`), then replace the UDF :

```py
@F.udf(output_schema)
def duplicate(no_of_occ, *args):
    dup_value = no_of_occ or 1
    return list((args,) * dup_value)
```

Comment: It is better to not use the udf, and instead make use of [array_repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_repeat).
See the details in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624745/pyspark-how-to-duplicate-a-row-n-time-in-dataframe)

Comment: @dsalaj for spark 2.4 or newer, yes. otherwise, you're stuck with UDF.