# Duplicate dataset with millions of rows using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to duplicate a dataset which has 30 rows to around 600 Million rows. I am currently using a for loop to iterate and perform union but it is taking a lot of time. Is there any better way to create duplicate rows in pyspark to this huge volume?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: how to duplicate a row n time in dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624745/pyspark-how-to-duplicate-a-row-n-time-in-dataframe)